# How can I resolve an inventory member who has a certain attribute?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to pass a specific host from my inventory as a parameter into a role. The host is part of a group but is demarcated by a variable that none of the other hosts have.

snippet of: hosts.yml

```
  dbservers:
       hosts:
        pg01:
         ansible_host: pg01.domain.com
         master_slave: master
        pg02:
         ansible_host: pg02.domain.com
         master_slave: slave
```

I want to be able to resolve pg01 based on the fact that the variable master_slave is set to 'master' such that I can call into a role like this:

```
      - name: Do something
        include_role:
         name: a.database.role.to.run.on.master
        vars:
          master_database_host: {{ something that resolves to pg01 }}
```

How can I resolve the appropriate host from inventory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a mix of [filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html) to extract the host you need:

```
tasks:
- debug:
    msg: '{{groups["group_name"] | map("extract", hostvars) | selectattr("master_slave", "equalto", "master") | map(attribute="inventory_hostname") | list}}'
```

Step by step:

`groups["group_name"]` is a list of all the hosts in the group `group_name`.

`map("extract", hostvars)` takes hostvars, a dictionary mapping the host to their variables, and extracts the hosts that are in `group_name` (i.e. `groups["group_name"]`). This results in a list containing the hosts in `group_name` mapped to their variables.

`selectattr("master_slave", "equalto", "master")` selects all hosts who have an attribute `master_slave` that equals to `master`. This result in a list with all the hosts that are masters mapped to their variables.

`map(attribute="inventory_hostname")` takes a list as input and returns the `inventory_hostname` attribute of every item. This result in a list with all the hosts that are masters.

Comment: Both responses are extremely helpful. Thank you both for taking the time to respond. Honestly, very much appreciated. I'm going to mark Alassane's response as the answer as it's well-articulated and broken down in a way that makes it more reusable. Thank you both!

Answer (score 3):

The play below (with json_query)

```
- hosts: dbservers
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        master_database_host: "{{ groups['dbservers']|
                                  map('extract',hostvars)|
                                  list|
                                  json_query('[?master_slave==`master`].inventory_hostname')|
                                  first }}"
    - debug:
        var: master_database_host
```

gives

```
ok: [pg02] => {
    "master_database_host": "pg01"
}
ok: [pg01] => {
    "master_database_host": "pg01"
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have to play with this. This is another interesting approach. Thank you for the response Vladimir!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use if else condition in vars to assign the values.
So your play should be Something like this.

```
  - name: Do something
    include_role:
     name: a.database.role.to.run.on.master
    vars:
      master_database_host: "{{ hostvars['pg01']['ansible_host'] if \"{{ hostvars['pg01']['master_slave'] }}\" == 'master' else 'default value goes here'}}"
```

Make sure to use proper escaping to make the conditional statements work.

The reason this works is Since ansible internally uses python to do stuff it is a way to use ternary operator in python.

Comment: He doesn't want to hard code the host that is the master,  he wants to find out which host has the attribute `master_slave` equal to `master`.

Comment: @AlassaneNdiaye Thanks for pointing it out. should I delete the answer or let it be there?

Comment: This is an interesting approach so it's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could also generate dynamic groups based on the master/slave status:

```
---
 - name: Play to create dynamic groups
   hosts: dbservers
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
    - name: Create groups based on variable master_slave
      group_by:
        key: "database-{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['master_slave'] }}"

 - name: Play to use the dynamic group database-master
   hosts: database-master
   gather_facts: false
   tasks:
    - name: Show hosts in group
      debug:
        msg: "This is {{ inventory_hostname }} from the dynamic database-master group."
```

The first play uses all dbservers and creates the dynamic groups based on the `master_slave` variable.
The dynamic groups are:

- `database-master`  containing pg01
- `database-slave`   containing pg02

The second play uses one of the dynamic created groups.

To use `group_by` the used variable has to exist for all hosts used.

This concept works best on automatic variable gathered by ansibles setup e.g. `ansible_distribution` to create dynamic groups based on the Distribution (Debian, Redhat, Ubuntu ...) or distribution versions using `ansible_distribution_version`.